# disable sunday in asp.net calender

Tags: asp.net, calendar

How to disable Sunday in asp.net calendar control? I am using C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a method for the dayrender event in the control. Something like this:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) return;

    e.Cell.ApplyStyle(new Style { BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray });
    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
}
```